How can I view changes to my React Native profile screen without navigating manually?
I'm working with React Native and Expo on a user profile file. Every time I want to save changes and see how they look, I'm redirected to the home page. I then have to manually navigate back to the profile screen on my phone to view the changes.
I already tried Fast Refresh, Hot Reloading, and have set the initial route to the profile screen for easier access. Despite these efforts, it still feels complex to do that everytime

You can try State Persistence.
You can Save and restore the navigation state when the app reloads. This ensures that you remain on the profile screen after a reload.
Consider the below example for your reference.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const PERSISTENCE_KEY = 'NAVIGATION_STATE';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const restoreState = async () => {
      try {
        const savedStateString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY);
        const state = savedStateString ? JSON.parse(savedStateString) : undefined;
        if (state) {
          setInitialState(state);
        }
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (isLoading) {
      restoreState();
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return null; // or a loading spinner
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      initialState={initialState}
      onStateChange={(state) =>
        AsyncStorage.setItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY, JSON.stringify(state))
      }
    >
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

Hope it will ease your coding experience.
